# Reference Error with one of my routes, even though it's the exact same as the others

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm getting such a weird error with one of my routes, but the others are set up just the same with no problems. my route `/getThePost` throws `ReferenceError: getThePost is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jakob\projects\planum-magic-functions\functions\index.js:13:26)`

I've tried changing the name of the route, I've tried putting the code inside one of the other routes to see if a reference error appears there instead(it doesn't), and I've tried moving the block of code... but after staring at it, it looks like it should work!

Please help guys.

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = require('express')();

const FBAuth = require('./util/fbAuth')

const { getAllPosts, createOnePost } = require('./handlers/posts');
const { login } = require('./handlers/users');

// Posts Routes

app.get('/posts', getAllPosts);
app.get('/post/:postId', getThePost);
app.post("/post", FBAuth, createOnePost);

//TODO delete post

//TODO update post

// Login Route

app.post('/login', login)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

posts.js

```
const { db } = require('../util/admin');

exports.getAllPosts = (req, res) => {
  db.collection("posts")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .get()
    .then(data => {
      let posts = [];
      data.forEach(doc => {
        posts.push({
          postId: doc.id,
          name: doc.data().name,
          images: doc.data().images,
          link: doc.data().link,
          info: doc.data().info,
          price: doc.data().price,
          itemCategory: doc.data().itemCategory,
          available: doc.data().available,
          highEnd: doc.data().highEnd,
          createdAt: doc.data().createdAt
        });
      });
      return res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
};

exports.getThePost = (req, res) => {
  let postData = {};
  db.doc(`/posts/${req.params.postId}`)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Post not Found" });
      }
      postData = doc.data();
      // postData.postId = doc.id;
      return res.json(postData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
};

exports.createOnePost = (req, res) => {
  const newPost = {
    name: req.body.name,
    images: req.body.images,
    link: req.body.link,
    info: req.body.info,
    price: req.body.price,
    itemCategory: req.body.itemCategory,
    available: req.body.available,
    highEnd: req.body.highEnd,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
  };
  db.collection("posts")
    .add(newPost)
    .then(doc => {
      res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: check this `const { getAllPosts, createOnePost } = require('./handlers/posts');`  line .`getThePost` not imported

Comment: Thank you. That's a frustrating thing to miss. Solved.

Comment: Which IDE editor you are using ? please use visual studio code ,Atom like this it will easily find the undefined variable while coding

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to import `getThePost` method here

```
const { getAllPosts, createOnePost, getThePost } = require('./handlers/posts');
```